# MongoSocketException : nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, socketexception, mongodb-cluster

I am trying to connect my spring boot service to a mongo cluster. Below is my application.yml configuration for mongo

```
      uri: mongodb://user:paswd@ip1:27017,ip2:27017,ip3:27017/dbname?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondary
```

but I am getting below error
`com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: ip1: nodename nor servname provided, or not known at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:143) at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip2: nodename nor servname provided, or not known at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1529) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:852) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1519) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1377) at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1305) at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ... 6 common frames omitted`

any solution for the same

I am expecting a solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

`ip1`, `ip2`, `ip3` should be either IP addresses or Names resolvable in a DNS lookup service.

You should have something like:

```
uri: mongodb://user:paswd@81.12.33.41:27017,81.12.33.42:27017,81.12.33.43:27017/dbname?authSource=adm...
```

or

```
uri: mongodb://user:paswd@hosthost1.somedomain.com:27017,hosthost2.somedomain.com:27017,hosthost3.somedomain.com:27017/dbname?authSource=adm...
```

Comment: I tried using both Ip addresses and names but still I am getting the same error